# Explode a json string present in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON string `substitutions` as a column in dataframe which has multiple array elements that I want to explode and create a new row for each element present in that array. There are other columns present in the df

My dataframe looks like this:

```
+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+--------+--------------------+
|           requestid|sourcepage|              cartid|                  tm|        dt|          customerId| usItemId|prefType|       substitutions|
+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+--------+--------------------+
|00-efbedfe05b4482...|  CHECKOUT|808b44cc-1a38-4dd...|2023-04-25 00:07:...|2023-04-25|f1a34e16-a6d0-6f5...|862776084| NO_PREF|{"id":{"productId...|
+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+--------+--------------------+
```

json string  column `substitutions`

```
[
    {
        "id": {
            "productId": "2N3UYGUTROQK",
            "usItemId": "32667929"
        },
        "usItemId": "32667929",
        "itemRank": 1,
        "customerChoice": false
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "productId": "2N3UYGUTRHQK",
            "usItemId": "32667429"
        },
        "usItemId": "32667429",
        "itemRank": 2,
        "customerChoice": true
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "productId": "2N3UYGUTRYQK",
            "usItemId": "32667529"
        },
        "usItemId": "32667529",
        "itemRank": 3,
        "customerChoice": false
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "productId": "2N3UYGUTIQK",
            "usItemId": "32667329"
        },
        "usItemId": "32667329",
        "itemRank": 4,
        "customerChoice": false
    },
    {"id": {
        "productId": "2N3UYGUTYOQK",
        "usItemId": "32663929"
    },
    "usItemId": "32663929",
    "itemRank": 5,
    "customerChoice": false
    }
]
```

I have tried the below but not getting desired results

```
df.select("*", f.explode(f.from_json("substitutions", MapType(StringType(),StringType()))))


+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+--------+--------------------+-------+
|           requestid|sourcepage|              cartid|                  tm|        dt|          customerId| usItemId|prefType|       substitutions|entries|
+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+--------+--------------------+-------+
|00-efbedfe05b4482...|  CHECKOUT|808b44cc-1a38-4dd...|2023-04-25 00:07:...|2023-04-25|f1a34e16-a6d0-6f5...|862776084| NO_PREF|[{"id":{"productI...|   null|
+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+--------+--------------------+-------+
```

What mistake am I doing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're not properly defining the schema of your json.

Let's start by making a simplified version of your `df` (you don't need to do this):

```py
someField='someVal'
substitutions="""
[
    {
        "id": {
            "productId": "2N3UYGUTROQK",
            "usItemId": "32667929"
        },
        "usItemId": "32667929",
        "itemRank": 1,
        "customerChoice": false
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "productId": "2N3UYGUTRHQK",
            "usItemId": "32667429"
        },
        "usItemId": "32667429",
        "itemRank": 2,
        "customerChoice": true
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "productId": "2N3UYGUTRYQK",
            "usItemId": "32667529"
        },
        "usItemId": "32667529",
        "itemRank": 3,
        "customerChoice": false
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "productId": "2N3UYGUTIQK",
            "usItemId": "32667329"
        },
        "usItemId": "32667329",
        "itemRank": 4,
        "customerChoice": false
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "productId": "2N3UYGUTYOQK",
            "usItemId": "32663929"
        },
        "usItemId": "32663929",
        "itemRank": 5,
        "customerChoice": false
    }
]"""

df = spark.createDataFrame([(someField, substitutions)], ["someField", "substitutions"])
```

Now, in order to be able to parse in the json (for example using the [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html) function like you're doing), you need to define the correct schema to be used. After having done that, you can `explode` your dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, explode, col

# Defining the json schema
schema = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("id", StructType([
        StructField("productId", StringType(), True),
        StructField("usItemId", StringType(), True),
    ]), True),
    StructField("usItemId", StringType(), True),
    StructField("itemRank", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("customerChoice", BooleanType(), True)
]))

output = df.withColumn("jsonStruct", explode(from_json(col("substitutions"), schema))) \
           .select("someField", "jsonStruct.*")

>>> output.show(truncate=False)
+---------+------------------------+--------+--------+--------------+
|someField|id                      |usItemId|itemRank|customerChoice|
+---------+------------------------+--------+--------+--------------+
|someVal  |{2N3UYGUTROQK, 32667929}|32667929|1       |false         |
|someVal  |{2N3UYGUTRHQK, 32667429}|32667429|2       |true          |
|someVal  |{2N3UYGUTRYQK, 32667529}|32667529|3       |false         |
|someVal  |{2N3UYGUTIQK, 32667329} |32667329|4       |false         |
|someVal  |{2N3UYGUTYOQK, 32663929}|32663929|5       |false         |
+---------+------------------------+--------+--------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `substitution`-column a string, or is it recognised as JSON by Spark?

If it's recognised as JSON you can simply remove the `from_json`:

```
df.select("*", f.explode("substitutions"))
```

Otherwise you have to provide the entire schema of your JSON. This worked for me with the JSON you posted above:

```
schema = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField('customerChoice', BooleanType()),
    StructField('id', StructType([StructField('productId', StringType()),
                                  StructField('usItemId', StringType())])),
    StructField('itemRank', LongType()),
    StructField('usItemId', StringType())
]))
df.select("*", f.explode(f.from_json('substitutions', schema)))
```

Comment: its just a string.. if i call explode then it fails.```cannot resolve 'explode(`substitutions`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not string```

Comment: Does it work when you provide the entire schema?

Comment: No. it does not return anything even after providing the schema..

Comment: That's strange. Can you run `df.select('substitutions').collect()[0]` and tell me what comes out?